# Flutter input text field with custom label position

Tags: flutter, dart, input

I would like to create below input in Flutter

[image]

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Label",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(getPt(4)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

But when using default behaviour Label goes to the top of border. Setting height for label breaks the whole input, so input text goes down, so this not helping.

I think I can put this to stack and position Label on my required position, but it want be part of input anymore, and will require watch value change on all fields, but maybe there is some other option?

Comment: How do you like to have `TextField` when it is on focused/ writing ?

Comment: The Custom InputBorder class worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75030874/16288080

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap it using `Container`,

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
    child: TextFormField(
      decoration:
          InputDecoration(labelText: "Label", border: InputBorder.none),
    ),
  );
```

[image]

Comment: This looks better, but if running validation on input, it puts error text inside container, so it looks weird

Comment: But putting container and textField with no border to stack makes job good, and still can use validation from flutter

Answer (score 0):

This is just an addition to the answer provided by @miftakhul-arzak

```
    Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
        child: TextFormField(
          decoration:
              InputDecoration(
                 labelText: "Label", 
                 border: InputBorder.none,
                 border: InputBorder.none,
                 focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                 enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                 errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                 disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                 focusedErrorBorder: InputBorder.none,
         ),
     ),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it seems a little bit late, i refactor TextFiledFrom for my issue and it will solve this problem in advanced. it just config like origin TextFiledForm with the same properties. you can find it in this link [TextFiledForm_BoxedLabelInside](https://gist.github.com/hamidwaezi/b3206907e75cc25b78e6d1b6b5584500)

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwNxP.png)

Comment: I think there is an additional space creation between textfields if there is more than one, how it is fixable?

Comment: i just uodate the link. @NijatNamazzade

Answer (score 0):

After adapting the previous solution, I couldn't adjust the position of label as I wanted, so I tried this now I can customize the position:

```
Container(
  height: 65, // can customize height 
  alignment: Alignment.center, 
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:18),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  color: Colors.grey[100],
),
child: TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelText: 'Email',
  labelStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.grey[700],
    fontSize: 16.0,
    letterSpacing: 0,
  ),
  border: InputBorder.none,
  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0, top:-2.0), // this can adjust the label and text position
  filled: true,
  fillColor: Colors.grey[100], //or transparent
),
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom, 
),
),
```