# Flutter: TextField or TextFormField label inside border using ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile, textfield

How can i make my `TextField` label float to the top but stay inside the `TextField` border (not at the edge of it) when my `TextField` widget is active?

Example of what i'm going for:

[image: Before active]

Becomes

[image]
This

Is this possible using the `inputDecorationTheme` on `ThemeData`? or do i have to make a wrapper Widget to accomplish this?

Would very much prefer to control it from an app wide `ThemeData`

Comment: check my answer on this question, will help u guy[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76041612/4336094)

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately i don't know how to do it with default tools, but i do it with another way, may be it will be helpful for you.

1. Create variable for `FocusNode` and border color inside of your widget:

```
// Use it to change color for border when textFiled in focus
FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

// Color for border
Color _borderColor = Colors.grey;
```

2. Inside of `initState` create listener for `textField`, if `textField` will be in focus, change border color to orange, otherwise change to grey:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // Change color for border if focus was changed
  _focusNode.addListener(() {
    setState(() {
      _borderColor = _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey;
    });
  });
}
```

3. Create `Container` with border for `textField`, add `focusNode` and set decoration to `textField`:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: _borderColor),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
  ),
  child: TextField(
    focusNode: _focusNode,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      border: InputBorder.none,
      labelText: "Amount",
      prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, minHeight: 0),
      prefixIcon: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18, horizontal: 8),
        child: Text("₦", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey)),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

4. Don't forget call `dispose` for `focusNode`:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  _focusNode.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Full code:

```
class TextFieldDesignPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TextFieldDesignPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextFieldDesignPageState createState() => _TextFieldDesignPageState();
}

class _TextFieldDesignPageState extends State<TextFieldDesignPage> {
  // Use it to change color for border when textFiled in focus
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  // Color for border
  Color _borderColor = Colors.grey;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Change color for border if focus was changed
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _borderColor = _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: _borderColor),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              border: InputBorder.none,
              labelText: "Amount",
              prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, minHeight: 0),
              prefixIcon: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18, horizontal: 8),
                child: Text("₦", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can I ask what about this code specifically keeps the label inside the text field? I am having lots of trouble getting this done and don't see anything here that actually explicitly keeps the label inside the field except perhaps the container wrapping...

Comment: okay I just ran your code and it works. I realize the difference is I'm using textFormField instead of textField. I wonder if this can be done with text form field?

Comment: @RobbB Yes, main trick is i am not use border for `TextField`, i use border for `Container` which contain `TextField`. I checked and it's also work correct with `TextFormField`. To prove it, change `TextField` to `TextFormField` in code from example.

Comment: Works perfectly for textFormField too, thanks! Only trouble I can see is customizing all other aspects of textFormField for error border and errorText etc. with this setup. Time to find a package to do this. And request feature from flutter team. Something like this should be somewhat more customizable

Comment: I have proposed a feature request [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110425) and included this post to help describe optimum action. I refer to this solution as hacky, which it is compared to a streamlined feature build into the textFormField directly. Hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: Hey Andrei, I decided to go with your code instead of waiting for Flutter.  It's actually quite sleek on second view. I wanted to know if you know of a way to change the container border color based on if there is an error with that textField. I am searching but don't really know where to start.

Comment: @RobbB you have `onChange` parameter for `TextFiled`, you can implement validation inside `onChange` and change color depends validation result.
Small example:
`
onChanged: (String text) {
  setState(() {
    _borderColor = text.length > 4 ? Colors.orange : Colors.red;
  });
},
`
Also you can use `TextEditingController` for advance controlling. 
If you have problem with that, create question with your specific example.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyInputTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? title;
  final String? helperText;
  final bool isSecure;
  final int maxLength;
  final String? hint;
  final TextInputType? inputType;
  final String? initValue;
  final Color? backColor;
  final Widget? suffix;
  final Widget? prefix;
  final TextEditingController? textEditingController;
  final String? Function(String? value)? validator;
  final Function(String)? onTextChanged;
  final Function(String)? onSaved;
  List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;

  static const int MAX_LENGTH = 500;

  MyInputTextField({
    this.title,
    this.hint,
    this.helperText,
    this.inputType,
    this.initValue = "",
    this.isSecure = false,
    this.textEditingController,
    this.validator,
    this.maxLength = MAX_LENGTH,
    this.onTextChanged,
    this.onSaved,
    this.inputFormatters,
    this.backColor,
    this.suffix,
    this.prefix,
  });

  @override
  _MyInputTextFieldState createState() => _MyInputTextFieldState();
}

class _MyInputTextFieldState extends State<MyInputTextField> {
  late bool _passwordVisibility;
  late ThemeData theme;

  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  Color _borderColor = getColors().primaryVariant;
  double _borderSize = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _passwordVisibility = !widget.isSecure;
    widget.textEditingController?.text = widget.initValue ?? "";

    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _borderSize = _focusNode.hasFocus ? 1.7 : 1;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    theme = Theme.of(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 55,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: _borderColor, width: _borderSize),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppDimens.radiusSmall),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
          child: TextFormField(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            controller: widget.textEditingController,
            autocorrect: false,
            obscureText: !_passwordVisibility,
            keyboardType: widget.inputType,
            cursorColor: Colors.white,
            validator: (value) {
              String? f = widget.validator?.call(value);
              setState(() {
                _borderColor = f != null ? getColors().redError : getColors().primaryVariant;
              });
              return f;
            },
            style: theme.textTheme.bodyText1,
            maxLength: widget.maxLength,
            inputFormatters: widget.inputFormatters,
            maxLines: 1,
            onChanged: (text) {
              widget.onTextChanged?.call(text);
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              counterText: "",
              hintStyle: theme.textTheme.subtitle1,
              floatingLabelStyle: theme.textTheme.headline6?.copyWith(color: getColors().textSubtitle),
              labelText: widget.title,
              helperText: widget.helperText,
              suffixIcon: getSuffixIcon(),
              prefixIcon: widget.prefix,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget? getSuffixIcon() {
    return widget.isSecure ? getPasswordSuffixIcon() : widget.suffix;
  }

  Widget? getPasswordSuffixIcon() {
    return IconButton(
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      focusColor: Colors.transparent,
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      icon: _passwordVisibility ? Icon(AppIcons.password_eye) : Icon(AppIcons.password_eye_blind),
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _passwordVisibility = !_passwordVisibility;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For those who might encounter a similar issue, here is my workaround. I created my implementation of `InputBorder` (similar to `OutlineInputBorder` or `UnderlineInputBorder`). The key difference is that it positions the label inside the border, eliminating any gap on the border for the label.

```
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     labelText: 'Floating label',
     helperText: 'Helper text works fine',
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
     border: OutlinedInputBorder(),
   ),
 );
```

[An example image of a `TextField` with the custom `InputBorder`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hidx.png)

I hope this solution can be convenient as it doesn't introduce any additional wrappers and can be used quite universally. For example, you can use this `InputBorder` implementation directly in your theme.

Here's the code of the custom border.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OutlinedInputBorder extends InputBorder {
  const OutlinedInputBorder({
    super.borderSide = const BorderSide(),
    this.borderRadius = const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
  });

  final BorderRadius borderRadius;

  @override
  bool get isOutline => false;

  @override
  OutlinedInputBorder copyWith({
    BorderSide? borderSide,
    BorderRadius? borderRadius,
  }) {
    return OutlinedInputBorder(
      borderSide: borderSide ?? this.borderSide,
      borderRadius: borderRadius ?? this.borderRadius,
    );
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions {
    return EdgeInsets.all(borderSide.width);
  }

  @override
  OutlinedInputBorder scale(double t) {
    return OutlinedInputBorder(
      borderSide: borderSide.scale(t),
      borderRadius: borderRadius * t,
    );
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder? lerpFrom(ShapeBorder? a, double t) {
    if (a is OutlinedInputBorder) {
      final OutlinedInputBorder outline = a;
      return OutlinedInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.lerp(outline.borderRadius, borderRadius, t)!,
        borderSide: BorderSide.lerp(outline.borderSide, borderSide, t),
      );
    }
    return super.lerpFrom(a, t);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder? lerpTo(ShapeBorder? b, double t) {
    if (b is OutlinedInputBorder) {
      final OutlinedInputBorder outline = b;
      return OutlinedInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.lerp(borderRadius, outline.borderRadius, t)!,
        borderSide: BorderSide.lerp(borderSide, outline.borderSide, t),
      );
    }
    return super.lerpTo(b, t);
  }

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(borderRadius
          .resolve(textDirection)
          .toRRect(rect)
          .deflate(borderSide.width));
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path()..addRRect(borderRadius.resolve(textDirection).toRRect(rect));
  }

  @override
  void paintInterior(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, Paint paint,
      {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    canvas.drawRRect(borderRadius.resolve(textDirection).toRRect(rect), paint);
  }

  @override
  bool get preferPaintInterior => true;

  @override
  void paint(
    Canvas canvas,
    Rect rect, {
    double? gapStart,
    double gapExtent = 0.0,
    double gapPercentage = 0.0,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
  }) {
    final Paint paint = borderSide.toPaint();
    final RRect outer = borderRadius.toRRect(rect);
    final RRect center = outer.deflate(borderSide.width / 2.0);
    canvas.drawRRect(center, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType) {
      return false;
    }
    return other is OutlinedInputBorder &&
        other.borderSide == borderSide &&
        other.borderRadius == borderRadius;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => Object.hash(borderSide, borderRadius);
}
```

Here's also a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Vanchel/d473ef4204ab54b6203020bc4f43c994).

There are relatively few differences from the `OutlineInputBorder` implementation to be fair, and most of the code is simply copied. The main change is that the `isOutline` getter returns `false` (similar to `UnderlineInputBorder`), as this value determines where the label will be positioned. Keep in mind that this value is taken into account for some other minor parameters, so you would possibly want to check how `InputDecorator` handles it to ensure that my solution suits your needs. For example, you may want to specify custom `contentPadding` value. I also modified the logic for drawing the border on the canvas to avoid adding any gap for the label, but there shouldn't be any unexpected issues here, as far as I understand.