# How to make the floating label stay within the border

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to achieve something like this in flutter;

[image]

The FloatingLabel is not directly at the border, is there an official way to achieve this in flutter.

I've tried adding padding to the label widget, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I believe there is no standard widget doing this. You may have to build your own or find a package that supplies this behavior.

Answer (score 18):

I was also surprised to see that it was not supported out of the box. After looking into the `InputBorder` class I understood that it can become quite complex.

Copying the whole `UnderlineInputBorder` class and swapping out the `onPaint` method with the one from the `OutlineInputBorder` class worked for me.

**The Custom InputBorder class:**

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomOutlineInputBorder extends InputBorder {
  /// Creates an underline border for an [InputDecorator].
  ///
  /// The [borderSide] parameter defaults to [BorderSide.none] (it must not be
  /// null). Applications typically do not specify a [borderSide] parameter
  /// because the input decorator substitutes its own, using [copyWith], based
  /// on the current theme and [InputDecorator.isFocused].
  ///
  /// The [borderRadius] parameter defaults to a value where the top left
  /// and right corners have a circular radius of 4.0. The [borderRadius]
  /// parameter must not be null.
  const CustomOutlineInputBorder({
    BorderSide borderSide = const BorderSide(),
    this.borderRadius = const BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
      topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
    ),
  })  : assert(borderRadius != null),
        super(borderSide: borderSide);

  /// The radii of the border's rounded rectangle corners.
  ///
  /// When this border is used with a filled input decorator, see
  /// [InputDecoration.filled], the border radius defines the shape
  /// of the background fill as well as the bottom left and right
  /// edges of the underline itself.
  ///
  /// By default the top right and top left corners have a circular radius
  /// of 4.0.
  final BorderRadius borderRadius;

  @override
  bool get isOutline => false;

  @override
  CustomOutlineInputBorder copyWith(
      {BorderSide? borderSide, BorderRadius? borderRadius}) {
    return CustomOutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: borderSide ?? this.borderSide,
      borderRadius: borderRadius ?? this.borderRadius,
    );
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions {
    return EdgeInsets.only(bottom: borderSide.width);
  }

  @override
  CustomOutlineInputBorder scale(double t) {
    return CustomOutlineInputBorder(borderSide: borderSide.scale(t));
  }

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width,
          math.max(0.0, rect.height - borderSide.width)));
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path()..addRRect(borderRadius.resolve(textDirection).toRRect(rect));
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder? lerpFrom(ShapeBorder? a, double t) {
    if (a is CustomOutlineInputBorder) {
      return CustomOutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide.lerp(a.borderSide, borderSide, t),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.lerp(a.borderRadius, borderRadius, t)!,
      );
    }
    return super.lerpFrom(a, t);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder? lerpTo(ShapeBorder? b, double t) {
    if (b is CustomOutlineInputBorder) {
      return CustomOutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide.lerp(borderSide, b.borderSide, t),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.lerp(borderRadius, b.borderRadius, t)!,
      );
    }
    return super.lerpTo(b, t);
  }

  /// Draw a horizontal line at the bottom of [rect].
  ///
  /// The [borderSide] defines the line's color and weight. The `textDirection`
  /// `gap` and `textDirection` parameters are ignored.
  @override
  void paint(
    Canvas canvas,
    Rect rect, {
    double? gapStart,
    double gapExtent = 0.0,
    double gapPercentage = 0.0,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
  }) {
    final Paint paint = borderSide.toPaint();
    final RRect outer = borderRadius.toRRect(rect);
    final RRect center = outer.deflate(borderSide.width / 2.0);
    canvas.drawRRect(center, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType) return false;
    return other is InputBorder && other.borderSide == borderSide;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => borderSide.hashCode;
}
```

**Usage:**

```dart
TextFormField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: CustomOutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  /// NOTE: Color argument won't work on border argument 
                  width: 1,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                )),
            enabledBorder: CustomOutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  /// NOTE: Color argument works here! :hooray: 
                  width: 1,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                )),
          )
),
```

Important Note: if you set only the `border` parameter of your TextField it will use the theme Colors for the onFocus(by default blue) and onError(by default red). If you want your `BorderSide(color: [yourCustomColor])` to work, you will have to pass the border arguments for each specific state:

```
errorBorder
focusedBorder
focusedErrorBorder
disabledBorder
enabledBorder
```

Comment: Why would you suggest copying the whole class instead of extending OutlineInputBorder and only overriding paint method?

Answer (score 1):

The answer above didn't exactly work for me, I had to tweak the paint method a bit:

```
  void paint(
    Canvas canvas,
    Rect rect, {
    double? gapStart,
    double gapExtent = 0.0,
    double gapPercentage = 0.0,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
  }) {
    final Paint paint = borderSide.toPaint();
    final Path outlinePath = getOuterPath(rect);
    canvas.drawPath(outlinePath, paint);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above unnecessarily extends the class InputBorder when we can simply extend UnderlineInputBorder and override the paint method.

```
class CustomOutlineInputBorder extends UnderlineInputBorder {

  const CustomOutlineInputBorder({
    super.borderSide,
    super.borderRadius = const BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
      topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
    ),
  })  : assert(borderRadius != null);

  @override
  void paint(
      Canvas canvas,
      Rect rect, {
        double? gapStart,
        double gapExtent = 0.0,
        double gapPercentage = 0.0,
        TextDirection? textDirection,
      }) {
    final Paint paint = borderSide.toPaint();
    final RRect outer = borderRadius.toRRect(rect);
    final RRect center = outer.deflate(borderSide.width / 2.0);
    canvas.drawRRect(center, paint);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `contentPadding` to add padding, then use `FloatingLabelBehavior.always` to keep the floating label always showing. You can specify different styles for the floating label, depending on whether it has focus. For example:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Email',
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
    floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
  ),
)
```